# Divide two variables in bash

Tags: bash, variables, divide

I am trying to divide two var in bash, this is what I've got:

```
var1=3;
var2=4;

echo ($var1/$var2)
```

I always get a syntax error.
Does anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: The actual issue here is the mistake (subshell/arithmetic syntax). After fixing that, there's the integer division issue: [Bash Division Keeps giving 0 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515025/bash-division-keeps-giving-0)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

shell parsing is useful only for integer division:

```
var1=8
var2=4
echo $((var1 / var2))
```

output:
    2

instead your example:

```
var1=3
var2=4
echo $((var1 / var2))
```

ouput:
    0

it's better to use bc:

```
echo "scale=2 ; $var1 / $var2" | bc
```

output:
    .75

*scale* is the precision required

Comment: The output of `bc` should be a string or a float number?

Comment: @Sigur the output is always a string

Comment: Is it possible to convert it to float or int?

Answer (score 26):

If you want to do it **without bc**, you could use awk:

```
$ awk -v var1=3 -v var2=4 'BEGIN { print  ( var1 / var2 ) }'
0.75
```

Comment: What is "without bc"?

Comment: bc is a terminal based calculator shipped with most distributions
https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc

Answer (score 20):

There are two possible answers here.

To perform integer division, you can use the shell:

```
$ echo $(( var1 / var2 ))
0
```

The `$(( ... ))` syntax is known as an *arithmetic expansion*.

For floating point division, you need to use another tool, such as `bc`:

```
$ bc <<<"scale=2; $var1 / $var2"
.75
```

The `scale=2` statement sets the precision of the output to 2 decimal places.

Comment: P.S. in my .zshrc, I have `calc () { echo "scale=2;$*" | bc | sed 's/\.0*$//'}` to do calculations. The latter `sed` is to remove trailing zeros, E.g. `100/10` we get `10` instead of `10.00`...

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=10
var2=5
echo $((var1/var2))
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explain what the error was.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Python for this task.
Type `python -c "print( $var1 / float($var2) )"`

Comment: This is honestly the simplest solution I could get working. The `bc` solution wasn't working at all for me.