# Divide the result of two grep and word count

Tags: zsh

I have a log file and I would like to divide the result of one grep and count by another grep and count.

```
$ echo $((cat log2.txt | grep timed\|error\|Error | wc -l)/(cat log2.txt | grep Duration | wc -l))
zsh: bad math expression: operator expected at `log2.txt |...'
```

It's ugly, doesn't work and I can probably do it in a better way but I don't know how.

Also I would like to know if it possible to id incrementaly on a log stream read by tail for example.

Comment: What output do you expect? Bash/sh can't do floating point arithmetic directly. I'd reach for a scripting language (Perl/Ruby/Python).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide two variables in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398014/divide-two-variables-in-bash)

Comment: You haven't escaped the `|` character enough. You've only escaped it to avoid the shell treating it as part of a pipeline, but `grep` still treats it as a literal character, not an alteration operator, unless it is escaped *again*. Either `grep timed\\\|\\\|error\\\|Error` or (more simply) `grep 'timed\|error\|Error'` or (simplest of all) `grep -E 'timed|error|Error'` (extended regular expressions *do* treat unescaped `|` as the alteration operator).

Comment: You *also* need to run the commands in a command substitution to use the output as operands in the arithmetic expression: `$(( $(cat ... wc -l) / $(cat ... wc -l) ))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should know that, both `grep|wc -l` will count **number of matched lines** instead of **occurrences**, I hope this is what you really want.

Regarding your requirement, indeed, your approach is ugly (7 processes), apart from the mistakes. The job can be done by a single awk line:

```
awk '/timed|[Ee]rror/{a++}/Duration/{b++}END{printf "%.2f\n",a/b}' log2.txt
```

The above line calculates the result based on matched number of **lines**, same as your `grep|wc -l`.

Comment: I needed exactly "number of matched lines" that's perfect. What {a++} means? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @BeniMio if you know C, or C++, you know a++. it is same as `a+=1`

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems:

1. You are trying to run shell commands directly inside an arithmetic expression.
2. You aren't passing the correct regular expression to `grep`.
3. You need to make sure at least one of the operands is a floating-point value to trigger `zsh`'s floating-point division.

Each pipeline can also be reduced to a single command; use input redirection instead of `cat`, and use the `-c` option to get the number of lines that match the regular expression.

```
echo $(( 1.0 * $(grep -c 'timed\|error\|Error' log2.txt) / $(grep -c Duration log2.txt))
```

---

Basic regular expressions treat unescaped `|` as a literal character, not an alteration operator.

```
$ echo foo | grep foo\|bar
$ echo foo | grep foo\\\|bar   # Pass a literal backslash as part of the regex
foo
$ echo foo | grep 'foo\|bar'   # Use '...' instead of explicitly escaping \ and |
foo
$ echo foo | grep -E 'foo|bar'  # Use extended regular expressions instead
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this additional explanations.