# Bash Division Keeps giving 0

Tags: bash

I know bash doesn't support long division, but here it goes. I looked up a bash work-around to giving me a supposed numeric value for the division. For example, this is what I got:

```
#!/bin/bash
SMALL_NUMBER=4
LARGE_NUMBER=56100

MATH_PROBLEM=$((100*$SMALL_NUMBER/$LARGE_NUMBER))
echo $MATH_PROBLEM
```

I execute the code and the output is always 0. I thought multiplying the expression by 100 would fix this but apparently not. Can someone tell me what is going on with this?

Comment: What do you think the answer should be?

Comment: The problem is `400 / 56100 < 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash only does integers, not floats; you must delegate the task to a tool such as `bc`